# Unity How to use Editor Script to remove StateMachineBehaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

**I have a problem use editor script to remove a statemachinebehaviour,like this:**

[image]

**I use AnimatorState.AddStateMachineBehaviour add the behaviour**

[image]

**The Documentation said use Object.Destroy,I use this api,but it appears:**

[image]

**I want to know how to use Editor Script to implement the function as "remove"**

[image]

**thanks for any idea!!!**

Comment: Instead of `Destroy()` try using `DestroyImmediate(GetComponent<AnimatorState>());`

Comment: I have used this but the problem is I can cannot remove the null reference when the real object have already been destroyed,I found some tips in follow link.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15225/how-do-i-remove-null-components-ie-missingmono-scr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the state machine behaviour you have to grab the state machine behaviour array, remove the behaviour that you're after, and then reassign the array.

Something along these lines should do it:

```c#
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations; 

//how you invoke this is up to you
[MenuItem("CONTEXT/StateMachineBehaviour/Remove Test")]
public static void RemoveBehaviour(MenuCommand command)
{
    Object selection = Selection.activeObject;

    AnimatorState state = selection as AnimatorState;

    if(state != null)
    {
        StateMachineBehaviour behaviour = command.context as StateMachineBehaviour;

        StateMachineBehaviour[] theBehaviours = state.behaviours;

        ArrayUtility.Remove(ref theBehaviours, behaviour);

        Undo.RegisterCompleteObjectUndo(state, "Removed behaviour");

        Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(behaviour);

        state.behaviours = theBehaviours;
    }                
}
```

This will remove the behaviour using the state machine dropdown menu, with added undo and redo support, an optional bonus.
Depending on how you want to handle the remove, this approach will change but in terms of removing the behaviour, this should be what you're after. 
Also, for animator state machines the approach is exactly the same, you just cast the selection object to an AnimatorStateMachine instead.

Hopefully this helps.